# Django form error: "Select a valid choice" on RadioSelect()

Tags: python, ajax, django, forms

Trying to figure out what's going wrong here. I have a ModelForm where I need a radio select between three colors. I get the following error:

*"Select a valid choice. This is not one of the available choices"*

models.py:

```
COLORS = (
    ('1', 'Röd'),
    ('2', 'Gul'),
    ('3', 'Blå'),)

class Poster(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    colors = models.IntegerField(choices=COLORS, default=2)
```

forms.py:

```
class PosterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PosterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Poster

        fields = ('title', 'colors')

        labels = {
                "title": "Rubrik",
                "colors": "Färg",
        }

        widgets = {
           'colors': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'choices': "[(1, 'Röd'), (2, 'Gul'),(3, 'Blå')]"}),
    }
```

template.html:

```
<div id="id_colors">
    <div class="radio"><label for="id_colors_0"><input class="" id="id_colors_0" name="colors" title="" type="radio" value="1" required /> Röd</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label for="id_colors_1"><input checked="checked" class="" id="id_colors_1" name="colors" title="" type="radio" value="2" required /> Gul</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label for="id_colors_2"><input class="" id="id_colors_2" name="colors" title="" type="radio" value="3" required /> Blå</label></div>
</div>


{% if form.colors.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>{{ form.colors.errors|escape }}</strong>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Happy for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out IntegerField isn't so keen on a number value inside a String. Changing this approach to use letters and a CharField did the trick.

models.py:

```
COLORS = (
    ('r', 'Röd'),
    ('y', 'Gul'),
    ('b', 'Blå'),)

class Poster(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    colors = models.CharField(choices=COLORS, max_length=1)
```

forms.py:

```
class PosterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PosterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Poster

        fields = ('title', 'colors')

        labels = {
                "title": "Rubrik",
                "colors": "Färg",
        }

        widgets = {
           *'colors': forms.RadioSelect(),*
    }
```

template.html:

```
<div id="id_colors">
    <div class="radio"><label for="id_colors_0"><input class="" id="id_colors_0" name="colors" title="" type="radio" value="r" required /> Röd</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label for="id_colors_1"><input checked="checked" class="" id="id_colors_1" name="colors" title="" type="radio" value="y" required /> Gul</label></div>
    <div class="radio"><label for="id_colors_2"><input class="" id="id_colors_2" name="colors" title="" type="radio" value="b" required /> Blå</label></div>
</div>


{% if form.colors.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>{{ form.colors.errors|escape }}</strong>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks Cheng for this post which helped me:
http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/05/25/django-create-a-radio-input-using-bootstrap3s-inline-style

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tuple for your choices! You're close but not quite on. Here's how it should look:

```
COLORS = [
    ('1', 'Röd'),
    ('2', 'Gul'),
    ('3', 'Blå')
]
```

See if that works. Be sure to mark the answer right if it does!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it when I come home. If it works I will definitely mark it!

Comment: Any other ideas? Maybe I need to define the options in my forms.py?